# pg_restore: error: options -d/--dbname and -f/--file cannot be used together

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I'm somewhat new to postgres and having trouble with restoring a local database with backup data using `pg_restore` and hoping to get some help. My situation is as follows:

- I have postgres running on Docker and I can access pgadmin.
- I have created a new server in pgadmin called 'flocal' with host name `postgres_db` user name `postgres` and port `5432`.
- In this new server, I have created a new database called `fdb`
- I have a backup folder called `fprod` on my local PC (mac if it matters) that contains a bunch of `.dat.gz` files inside.

Now I navigate to this backup folder and in my local terminal I run this:

```
pg_restore -h postgres_db -p 5432 -U postgres -d fdb -f fprod
```

And I get the following error message below. I've tried changing my hostname to just `-h localhost` but no difference.

```
pg_restore: error: options -d/--dbname and -f/--file cannot be used together
```

What am I missing and doing wrong? Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) `-f`  does not specify the input file, it specifies an *output* file e.g. for the `--list` command.

So you need:

```
pg_restore -h postgres_db -p 5432 -U postgres -d fdb fprod
```

Comment: Got it. But I also had to change host name to localhost. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

`pg_restore` can restore to either a database(`-d`) or a file(`-f`).

If you restore to a file the minimum you need to do is:

```
pg_restore -f some_file.sql the_dump_file.out
```

This creates a plain text version of a custom format dump file.

If you dump to a database then the minimum is:

```
pg_restore -h some_host -d the_database -U a_user the_dump_file.out
```

You need to include the host(`-h`)/database(`-d`)/user(`-U`) combination so `pg_restore` knows how to connect to the appropriate database. Host is the address(socket/IP) that the server is listening on. That is why you needed to change to `-h localhost`.